# Ptyhon DTLS v1.2 handshake with PSK

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking, network-programming, philips-hue

Has anyone successfully done the DTLS handshake with Philips Hue Bridge with Python?
For those who don't know these are the requirements for the DTLS handshake:

```
UDP port 2100 is used for DTLS handshaking and streaming. Only DTLS mode version 1.2 with Pre-Shared Key (PSK) Key exchange method with TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 set as Cipher Suite is supported
```

I plan to make an open-source framework in Python that will make everything easier to develop with Philips Hue but I'm stuck with making the handshake.

I've tried using a few libraries that should solve the problem with the DTLS since Python doesn't have a native solution:

- python-mbedtls
- python3-dtls
- pyopenssl
- pyopenssl-psk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is looking for a solution, I've made a library that solves the problem and should be easy to use: https://github.com/hrdasdominik/hue-entertainment-pykit
It's on the PyPI repository so you can install it via pip.

Comment: can you show how to use it and give a brief explanation of how it works?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35574938)